# Ruby - Assigning boxes with x number of lunches to ovens with specific capacities

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I need to write an algorithm that assigns boxes with a certain amount of lunches to ovens that have a certain capacity.

So for example I have:

Oven 1 - capacity 25

Oven 2 - capacity 25

Oven 3 - capacity 10

Box 1 - 3 lunches

Box 2 - 12 lunches

Box 3 - 2 lunches

Box 4 - 5 lunches

Box 5 - 20 lunches

Box 6 - 4 lunches

Box 7 - 5 lunches

These idea is to fill up as little ovens as possible with the maximum amount of boxes.

So in this example the outcome would be:

Oven 1 - capacity 25

Box 1 - 3 lunches

Box 2 - 12 lunches

Box 4 - 5 lunches

Box 7 - 5 lunches

25/25 filled

Oven 2 - capacity 25

Box 5 - 20 lunches

Box 6 - 4 lunches

24/25 filled

Oven 3 - capacity 10

Box 3 - 2 lunches

2/10 filled

Comment: This sounds like a variant of a combinatorial optimization problem known as the [Knapstack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: ✏️This is an assignment. If you want help, show us **what you tried** and try and articulate where you're having problems with your understanding of the requirements and/or your code.

Comment: This can also be solved (in this instance) with just filling the ovens till you can't fit the next item, in order, e.g. `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which generalizes [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) by requiring that some or all of the variables take integer values only. Here all the variables are restricted to the values of zero and one. These are often referred to a *binary variables*.

Let

l<sub>i</sub> : number of lunches in box i

c<sub>j</sub> : capacity of oven j

We may define the following binary variables:

o<sub>j</sub> : equals 1 if oven j is used, else equals 0

b<sub>ij</sub> : equals 1 if box i is assigned to oven j, else equals 0

The formulation of the 0-1 integer program is as follows.

minimize Σ<sub>j</sub>o<sub>j</sub>

subject to the following constraints.

Σ<sub>i</sub>l<sub>i</sub>*b<sub>ij</sub> <= c<sub>j</sub>*o<sub>j</sub> for each j

Σ<sub>j</sub>b<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each i

The first group of constraints require that for each oven j that is used (i.e., o<sub>j</sub> = 1) the number of lunches assigned to that oven does not exceed the oven's capacity. If the oven is not used the right side of the inequality equals zero, so no boxes can be assigned to that oven.

The second group of constraints ensures that each box of lunches is assigned to exactly one oven.

---

If there are N ovens and M boxes it is seen that there are

N + M*N binary variables

and

N + M constaints

For the example given, where N = 3 and M = 7, there are N + M*N = 24 variables and N + M = 10 constraints.

---

Integer programs can be solved with any of several commercial or open-source optimization packages (e.g., [GUROBI](https://www.gurobi.com/resource/switching-from-open-source/) and [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer)).

The time required to solve a integer program is very difficult to predict. Whereas linear programs with thousands of variables and constraints can often be solved in at most a few seconds, some integer programs of seemingly modest size my not solve in a lifetime.